# How big should the sample be in my translation quality assessment study?

Tags: sample-size

I'm doing my master's thesis on translation quality assessment of academic textbooks of a language pair. With respect to sampling, I'm encountering some questions.

I'm assessing the academic textbooks of a given field. Out of about 70 translations, I have decided to sample about 35 books which are read the most and from different subsections of the field. According to my literature review the best unit of translation and therefore assessment is sentence. So, I have decided to to do stratified random sampling from the sentences of the books. I am an independent researcher, my time and resources are limited, and analyzing each sentence by applying the chosen model takes a lot of time.

Here, the problem of generalizability comes to the surface. I overestimated the number of pages of the books. I assume that each book has 500 pages while in reality each book averagely has far fewer pages, maybe around 250. And again I estimate the number of sentences in each page the most possible: usually each page has 10 to 20, so I assume that each page has 20. Then, I multiply the number of pages and the number of sentences and the number of books, and reach the number of 300000 sentences.

To limit the sample size, I've decided to set the confidence level at 90% And the margin of error at 10%. By doing so, out of 300000 sentences 68 sentences (that is, 2 sentences from each book selected absolutely randomly) would suffice. Is that right? Do you think this sample size is defensible?

By the way, my advisor believes instead of this way, it is best to pick 3-6 pages from each book and assess them with a less detailed, less time-consuming model. In some respects he is right, but then the workload will be huge (at least, with the present model). I believe in finding the most from sentences, he believes n finding even less from a bigger unit of text (at least 1 single page).

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're measuring & what you want to investigate? You've presumably calculated the sample size assuming a binomial sampling model & want to estimate the probability of a sentence's being correctly or incorrectly translated.

Comment: @Scortchi I am going to find and categorize translation errors in each pair of source text-target text and finally talk about what kind of errors are common in translating academic textbooks.

Comment: What's that got to do with your sample size calculation? If you don't find any errors in the 68 sentences, are you just going to report an upper 95% confidence bound of 4.4% & call it a day?

Comment: @Scortchi I have started analyzing them. They are replete with errors. There's the problem of generalizability, though.

Comment: Well, I was giving an extreme example. The point was that this sample size calculation is to do with the precision of an estimate of a proportion & nothing more, whereas exploratory analysis or comparison of the prevalence of different types of errors would probably benefit from a greater sample size. Anyway, what do you want to estimate? What population do you want to generalize to?